# What to call part of a url

Tags: terminology, uri

So I've got a base Uri of:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/
```

Ok, you can append various sub paths such as this to their API:

```
/me/friends
/322323232
etc.
```

So you'd end up with something like this for their API calls:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=2343sdfse43.....
```

What would you call the `/me/friends` portion of this url?  I mean it's not a "Uri".  The Uri is the first part.

There's got to be some kind of official name to call sub directories under the Uri right?  or no?

Comment: You may want to have a look at this document: http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3305.txt (PS: it's URI, all caps)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The URI (Uniform Resource Identifier) is the **entire string**. Also note that URL (Uniform Resource Locator) and URI are not the same; URL is a subset of URI. See [Wikipedia's article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI) for information.

In your example, `/me/friends` is known as the **path**.

Comment: Indeed. See [here](http://labs.apache.org/webarch/uri/rfc/rfc3986.html#components) for more details.

Comment: It's known as the hostname or domain.

Comment: duh yea.  I guess I was originally right when naming the entire request url a Uri in some of my older code..

Answer (score 4):

I would call it the "path" or "route."

Comment: Isn't "route" how the path is handled?